# Close APK installer dialog

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, apk

I work on an enterprise app with a custom update (w/o Google Play). I download and run the update directly from the APK:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

It brings me the installer dialog. After installing the update I relaunch my app with a broadcast receiver:

```
<receiver android:name=".content.SilentUpdateReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

public class SilentUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

The app opens in the foreground, but the installer dialog remains to stay in the background.

[image: apk install dialog]

How to close this dialog programmatically?

Comment: You can't do that.